# Concat arrays into array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I have a function that has an array with the months of the year. In my function i delete some words of the month name.
My function is

```js
var array = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var result = [array[i].slice(0, 3)];
  console.log(result);
}
```

The result is `["Ene"] ... ["Dic"]`
But i want have some like this: `["Ene", ... , "Dic"]`
How i can concat the result in a unique array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:**

In OP code, the statement

```
var result = [array[i].slice(0, 3)];
```

is creating a variable `result` in each iteration of the `for` loop and assigning an array having one element in it, so after loop finishes execution, the `result` variable will only contain the last element `["Dic"]`.

**Solution:**

To add the elements to array, use [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

```js
var array = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'];

// Declare new empty array
var result = [];

// Loop over main array
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  // Add the new item to the end of the result array
  result.push(array[i].slice(0, 3));
}
console.log(result);
```

---

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var array = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'];

var months = array.map(function(e) {
  return e.substr(0, 3);
});
console.log(months);
```

Comment: array.map is probably the cleaner option here as it build the new array by applying a function to the old one, in this case, a substr(0,3) function.

Answer (score 0):

Have `result` be an empty array and `push()` to it.

```js
var result = [];
var array = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'];
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
   result.push(array[i].slice(0,3));
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

> The slice() method returns the selected elements in an array, as a new
>   array object. - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp
>
> The substr() method extracts parts of a string, beginning at the
>   character at the specified position, and returns the specified number
>   of characters. - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp